# Graphql hotchocolate - How to stitch 2 schemas from public rest api in dotnet

Tags: api, .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

My goal is to use 2 public apis such as https://randomuser.me/api and universities.hipolabs.com/search?country=Australia

Build a gateway to retreive object results from both APIs.

For example use "country" in randomuser api and fetch universities by that country.